How can I set a value in formik with react-bootstrap componenet?
I have a simple formik form with a react-bootstrap based component, how can I set a value in formik?
There are only two initial values for simplicity.
If I set an initial value and then pass a value via the value prop then the it does not display in the UI and when I submit the passed value does not show up in the console.
I have added a code sandbox link
Set Value in formik code sandbox -  https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/setvalue-formik-48qsjd
Any help much appreciated.
